# macOS public beta stopped updating

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program

The macOS Sierra 10.12.1 public beta train keeps chugging along, but my MacBook is stuck on 10.12.1 public beta 2 (16B2333a), which I installed over two weeks ago. Apparently [the current public beta is public beta 4](http://www.macrumors.com/2016/10/11/apple-seeds-macos-sierra-10-12-1-beta-4/).

I've tried going to System Preferences → App Store → Your computer is set to receive beta updates and toggling it off, then reinstalling the update enabler from [beta.apple.com](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/guide#macos) to turn it back on (since the preference disappears when you turn it off.)

Is there any way to convince App Store to show me updates past public beta 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure if this solved my problem, and I'd welcome a better answer, but after asking, I

1. Toggled beta updates off
2. Rebooted
3. Re-enrolled my Mac; no updates found
4. Ran `softwareupdate -l`; but no updates were found
5. Ran `softwareupdate --dump-state` to try to debug
6. While I was rooting around in the dumped state and downloading and inspecting files, Public Beta 5 became available and showed up both in App Store.app and `softwareupdate -l`

I'm guessing that the toggling off and re-enrolling of beta updates made me eligible for the *next* Public Beta; though I'm not sure. I'm posting because perhaps that strategy may help someone else.